# Replicating Excel VLOOKUP in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vlookup

So I have 2 tables, Table 1 and Table 2, Table 2 is sorted with the dates- recent dates to old dates. So in excel when I do a lookup in Table 1 and the lookup is done from Table 2, It only picks the first value from table 2 and does not move on to search for the same value after the first.
So I tried replicating it in python with the merge function, but found out it gets to repeat the value the number of times it appears in the second table.

```
pd.merge(Table1, Table2, left_on='Country', right_on='Country', how='left', indicator='indicator_column')
```

TABLE1
[image]

TABLE2
[image]

Merger result
[image: Merger result]

Expected Result(Excel vlookup)
[image]

Is there any way this could be achieved with the merge function or any other python function?

Comment: try removing the duplicate entries first, may be `pd.merge(Table1, Table2.groupby("Country",as_index=False).first(), left_on='Country', right_on='Country', how='left')` , and please do not post images of data as a question as no one can copy and reproduce from an image

Comment: @anky, thanks a lot, sorry for the images though

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Since you want a straight up Vlookup, just use join.  It appears to find the very first one.

```
table1.join(table2, rsuffix='r', lsuffix='l')
```

[image]

The docs seem to indicate it performs similarly to a vlookup: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

I'd recommend approaching this more like a SQL join than a Vlookup. Vlookup finds the first matching row, from top to bottom, which could be completely arbitrary depending on how you sort your table/array in excel. "True" database systems and their related functions are more detailed than this, for good reason.

In order to join only one row from the right table onto one row of the left table, you'll need some kind of aggregation or selection - So in your case, that'd be either MAX or MIN.

The question is, which column is more important?  The date or age?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':['GERM','LIB','ARG','BNG','LITH','GHAN'],
    'Name':['Dave','Mike','Pete','Shirval','Kwasi','Delali']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':['GERM','LIB','ARG','BNG','LITH','GHAN','LIB','ARG','BNG'],
    'Age':[35,40,27,87,90,30,61,18,45],
    'Date':['7/10/2020','7/9/2020','7/8/2020','7/7/2020','7/6/2020','7/5/2020','7/4/2020','7/3/2020','7/2/2020']
})
df1.set_index('Country')\
.join(
    df2.groupby('Country')\
    .agg({'Age':'max','Date':'max'}), how='left', lsuffix='l', rsuffix='r')
```

[image: idk why my screenshots always end up being so humongous]

Answer (score 0):

Typing this in the blind as you are including your data as images, not text.

```py
# The index is a very important element in a DataFrame
# We will see that in a bit
result = table1.set_index('Country')

# For each country, only keep the first row
tmp = table2.drop_duplicates(subset='Country').set_index('Country')

# When you assign one or more columns of a DataFrame to one or more columns of
# another DataFrame, the assignment is aligned based on the index of the two
# frames. This is the equivalence of VLOOKUP
result.loc[:, ['Age', 'Date']] = tmp[['Age', 'Date']]
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
```